# Having an issue downloading a file from firebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am having a trouble downloading a file from firebase storage , it just run without any errors but doesn't download any files.

```
fire = firebase.Firebase(firebaseConfig)

authen = fire.auth()
user = authen.sign_in_with_email_and_password("ahmed@gmail.com" , "123456")
user = authen.refresh(user['refreshToken'])

storage = fire.storage()
storage.child("uploaded").child("uploadedFile.txt").download("downloaded.txt" , user["idToken"])
print("done")
```

I tried to check the **init**.py file in the firebase module , I found another solution is giving the credentials to firebase class but I don't know what is it.
Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

[Try](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#download)

```
…
storage.child("uploadedFile.txt").download("downloaded.txt")
print("done")
```